# How to fix the warning "label `' multiply defined"

Tags: r, label, latex, knitr, texreg

I am running an lm regression in r, where there are categorical variables and numerical variables. I am usig knitr to compile the Rnw file to make a pdf. I use texreg to make latex regression tables. But when I do the compiling, it reported that lots of lines "Label `' multiply defined". 
Is it a must that we should assign label to each variable in the regression? But for those factor variables, I tried to assign label, like label(data$var) <- "name", then the warning is "label" command cannot be applied to the class of factor. Now I am really confused. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: "Label 'multiply defined'" means you're issuing `\label{<something>}` more than once for the exact same `<something>` inside your LaTeX code.

Comment: Fyi. I get this error issuing \cite{} ...

Answer (score 4):

A perl-bash snippet has been developed [here](http://www.mawode.com/blog/blog/2012/03/21/finding-duplicate-latex-labels/):

```
perl -nE "say $1 if /(\\label[^}]*})/" *.tex | sort | uniq -c
```

which searches the .tex file for all `\label{...}`s using the regular expression `\\label[^}]*}` and then sot-group them by the number of occurance. Just fix the labels with more than 1 occurance (duplicated ones) and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `texreg` package to create multiple tables for inclusion in a LaTeX document. When you use the `texreg` function, a LaTeX table is created. But all tables have the same line:

```
\label{table:coefficients}
```

LaTeX complains that this same label was included multiple times, thus not allowing you to reference any specific table.

To remedy the situation, you can include the `label` argument in your texreg calls as in the following example:

```
texreg(mymodel, label = "firsttable")
```

Make sure you change the label for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `perl -lne 'print unless /^\s*1/'` at the end of `perl -nE "say $1 if /(\\label[^}]*})/" *.tex | sort | uniq -c`, so you get just the multi-defined labels.

`perl -nE "say $1 if /(\\label[^}]*})/" *.tex | sort | uniq -c | perl -lne 'print unless /^\s*1/'`